# Modify ruby/sinatra POST to receive JSON array of entries

Tags: ruby, json, sinatra

My sinatra code currently accepts a single POST at a time, but I want to be able to post an array of entries. What's the best way to modify this code to allow multiple entries to be posted in a single POST request?

```
post '/api/events' do
  body = JSON.parse request.body.read
  event = Event.create(
    event_type:    body['event_type'],
    event_subtype:    body['event_subtype'],
    note: body['note'],
    user_email: body['user_email'],
    user_system: body['user_system'],
    user_software: body['user_software']   
  )
  status 201
  format_response(event, request.accept)
end
```

Comment: Show us your attempts to solve this.

Comment: I've been looking for a tidy way to do a `for each` and failed so far, so that's about it..

Answer (score 2):

The JSON coming from the client has to be properly structured so that the server can parse it as an array of events i.e. the server would receive a query string such as:

If the mime-type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`:

```
?events[][event_type]=Good&events[][note]=neato
```

That query string will be parsed as an array of events because of the brackets `events[]` where each member will be in the following brackets `[event_type]`. In other words (code):

```
root_key[sub_key]=value => { root_key: { sub_key: value } }
root_key[][sub_key]=value => { root_key: [{ sub_key: value }] }
```

If the mime type is `application/json` and you're using an ajax library such as jQuery you can specify `dataType: 'json'` and just give it an object in the data option such as:

```
data: { events: [{ events_type: 'Good', ...}, ...] }
```

For example:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: 'json',
  data: { events: [{ events_type: "Good", note: "neato" }] }
});
```

The query string or json will be parsed into:

```
body = JSON.parse request.body.read
body # => [{ event_type: "Good", note: "neato" }]
```

With ActiveRecord you can pass that array directly to `Event.create(body["events"])`.

Comment: Great tips, thanks! `Event.create(body["events"])` looks perfect. Unfortunately I'm not using jQuery to send API data but Objective-c (in the form of an OS X app) and I'm having problems converting an NSMutableArray of NSDictionary objects to JSON that has the 'events' key at the start that you describe. The brackets appear to be right, just missing the events: key

Comment: Cool. Have you tried creating an NSDictionary with a key of "events" and a value of an NSArray of NSDictionary events?

Comment: Ok, your suggestion worked and I've got the JSON properly formatted, but I'm getting a server error that I'm struggling to debug when using `Event.create(body["events"])`

Comment: And that error is? Want to start a new question and post a link here (remember to include the full stack trace in the question)?